# javascript require package from npm returns 1

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

I'm trying to build this as a npm-package:

Test.tsx:

```
import React from "react";

export default class Test extends React.Component {
    public render() {
        return (
            <h1>
                Hallo
            </h1>
        )
    }

    public blub() {
        return 12;
    }
}
```

index.tsx:

```
import Test from './Test';
module.exports = { Test }
```

It's an ejected create-react-app project.
the compiled file (/dist/static/js/main.chunk.js) includes this lines:

```
module.exports = {
    Test: _Test__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__[/* default */ "a"]
};
```

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "npmreacttestcrm",
  "version": "0.1.12",
  "private": false,
  "main": "dist/static/js/main.chunk.js",
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js",
    "publish:npm": "npm run build && npm publish && python updater.py"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "jest": {
    ...
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app",
      "@babel/preset-typescript"
    ]
  }
}
```

If I try to import the package in an other project, require or import just return 1

```
import Test1 from 'npmreacttestcrm';
console.log('test1', Test1);
const Test = require("npmreacttestcrm");
console.log('test', Test);
```

console:
    test1 1
    test 1

How do I correctly import my package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry my bad, I still had my files chunked and just imported one of them.
Now there is just one bundle.js and I can import it.